# python Combine two/more lists and add to database

Tags: python, mysql, list

I need to combine two lists and insert into the database as respective rows!not seperately:

Consider i have two lists:

```
qw=['bike car', ' ', 'car', 'car bike car', ' ', 'bike']
qw1=['good car and benz', ' ', '', '', ' ', 'and 180']
```

I need to combine them as:

```
**name**        **name1**
bike car        good car and benz
...             ....
...             ....
```

My coding:

```
for name,name1 in qw,qw1:
       cursor.execute(
       '''INSERT INTO Detail1 (Names,Hobby)
          VALUES (%s, %s)''',
         (name,name1))

       db.commit()
```

But i get error as too many tuples!
Please help,Answers will be appreciated!

Comment: Why not use `qw.extend(qw1)` and just use straight forward iteration?

Comment: Try `for name,name1 in zip(qw, qw1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want this:

```
for (name,name1) in zip(qw,qw1):
       cursor.execute(
       '''INSERT INTO Detail1 (Names,Hobby)
          VALUES (%s, %s)''',
         (name,name1))

       db.commit()
```

The database seems to be in no way connected to what your problem is.